# SQL query for multiple values of a column

Tags: sql

I have db with names etc with date of birth. How can I get count of columns for all 12 months of the dates?

Comment: You should revise the question to include the format of the date column.  It would also benefit you to review the manual for the `Date()` function.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Exact code depends on the database you use; you should, somehow, "extract" month from date of birth in order to `GROUP BY` it.

In Oracle, you might have done it as

```
select to_char(date_of_birth), 'mon') dob_month,
       count(*)
from your_table
group by to_char(date_of_birth, 'mon');
```

or

```
select extract(month from date_of_birth) dob_month,
       count(*)
from your_table
group by extract(month from date_of_birth);
```